# LINQ IQueryable Nested Loops

Tags: asp.net, linq

I am trying to replicate this loop as an IQueryable:

```
        foreach (var book in BookList)
        {
            foreach (var a in book.Authors)
            {
                if (a.AuthorId.ToString() == Id)
                {
                    AuthorView = new AuthorViewModel(a, item.BookId);
                }
            }
        }
```

I have tried:

```
var Test = _context.Book.Include(x => x.Authors)
  SelectMany(y => y.Authors).ToList().FirstOrDefault(x => x.AuthorId.ToString() == Id)
.Select(x => new AuthorViewModel(x, ??.BookId);
```

But I get stuck trying to create the object AuthorViewModel as it requires the BookId that I can no longer access. Is there a way of passing the book Id down?

Sorry, just release the example doesn't make sense.

Books is a table in a database.
Authors is a table in the database which contains many authors.

```
Book:
BookId
Authors

Authors:
AuthorId
Name
DOB
```

AuthorList should have been BookList (List). I have corrected this.

I am trying to locate an author based on an author id - and return it in an object (Author, BookId (from the book table))

Comment: can you share `AuthorList` type?

Comment: Why `a.AuthorId.ToString() == Id`? If the underlying type is a number change *the parameter* to the correct type and write `a.AuthorId == Id`. This matters *a lot*. Forcing a conversion to string prevents the use of any index that covers `AuthorId`. If `Id` contains leading 0s or spaces, the comparison will fail

Comment: Your loop shows one thing, the query something completely different. What are you actually trying to do? Explain what you want, not how you tried to achieve it. Do you want a separate record for each book and author? Or just the *first* author for each book?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is I would do:

```
var id= int.Parse(Id);
var Test = _context.Book.Include(x => x.Authors)
                        .SelectMany(item => item.Authors
                                                .Where(y => y.AuthorId == id)
                                                .Select(b => new AuthorViewModel(b,item.BookId));
```

You can filter and project inside of the `SelectMany` extension method

Comment: Thanks - I was originally doing something very similar to this. Turns out I needed to add '.First()' to covert it from an IQueryable to the object I wanted.

Comment: You're welcome, `SelectMany` is to flatten collections into a single collection but you can also see it like cross join in sql, so in the operations of the inner collection you can use the root object

Answer (score 1):

If you drill down on the Authors (SelectMany) then you have no way to go back to books. The condition on AuthorId needs to be handled internally.

```
var Test = _context.Book.Include(x => x.Authors)
          .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Authors.Any(y => y.AuthorId.ToString() == Id))
          .Select(x => new AuthorviewModel(x,x.BookId);
```

of course this will select only one book per author, just like your code. I wonder if your desired behaviour is to get all books instead...

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need `SelectMany` or `Include` at all. You can go like;

```
_context.Book
    .Where(b => b.Authors.Any(a => a.AuthorId.ToString() == Id))
    .Select(b => new AuthorViewModel(b.Authors.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AuthorId.ToString() == Id), b.BookId);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, convert `Id` to a number instead of trying to convert `AuthorId` to a string. Applying any kind of function on a table field means that indexes that cover it can't be used. Instead of a fast search based on an ID, you'll have a full table scan that converts values to strings before comparing them using *string* semantics. If the `Id` parameter contains any leading zeros, the comparison will fail.

As for the LINQ query itself, the easiest way is to use the query form. If you want to return one record for each book and author combination, you can write :

```
var id=int.Parse("ID");

var query= from book in _context.Book
           from author in book.Authors
           where author.AuthorID = id
           select new AuthorViewModel(author,book.BookId);
var records=query.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks - I will convert to int in future :)